# Is there an exception to running a fourth ground wire when upgrading a sub panel

Tags: electrical, subpanel, grounding-and-bonding

I am upgrading a 1950 homes sub panel from a fuse panel to a breaker panel. It’s is a three wire system running the fuse panel. The panel is down stairs on a interior wall about 50 feet from the main outside panel. All the walls are finished Sheetrock. It’s a two story house with concrete bottom floor and that is where the panel is located. I want to avoid cutting Sheetrock. The panel only has three ground wires total. All the receptacles are two wire only receptacles. The grounds come from the cooktop, in cabinet oven and water heater.

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the panel please?

Comment: To know if there are exceptions we would need to know your location. In some jurisdictions they will allow 3 wire in this case to get rid of the fuse panel and install circuit breakers, these exceptions are getting smaller all the time.

Comment: I do not have pictures of the inside of panel. 

I am in central NC

Comment: Are the receptacles, lights, etc. connected with cables or with wires in conduit?

Comment: No the old two wire paper wrapped cable no conduit

Comment: There is an exception if the house was built before the fourth wire was required and the sub panel is not accessible without removing wall covering like Sheetrock you do not have to run the fourth wire. I only know this to be true in NC